# Why is there excess pressure on the concave side of liquid meniscus in a capillary tube?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, surface-tension, capillary-action

I understand the derivation for the expression of excess pressure inside a liquid drop, but, most books also use this concept of excess pressure for explaining the rise of liquid column inside a capillary tube dipped in a liquid, saying that an excess pressure exists on the concave side of the liquid meniscus, but, I don't understand how the drop analogy works on a liquid meniscus, in a drop, the force of surface tension on a hemisphere of the drop is exerted by the other hemisphere of the drop, however, in a liquid meniscus, there is no other hemisphere to exert a force of surface tension on the meniscus, then how is there an excess pressure on the concave side of the meniscus? Rather it can be said that the force of surface tension acts on the meniscus opposite to the direction in which it would act if it were a drop, as the liquid is on the convex side of the meniscus(for contact angle less than 90°), hence the force of surface tension must be pulling the meniscus towards the liquid?

Here I have tried deriving it, but I am getting an excess pressure on the convex side instead, please tell where I went wrong?
[image]
[image]

Comment: > *"there is no other hemisphere"* Yes, but there is the glass tube, which attracts the water more than the air does, similarly to water in one hemisphere attracting the neighboring water in the other hemisphere more than the air does. So here we have similar surface tension force, only it is due to glass, not the water.

Comment: Pressure has to be 1 atmosphere at the level of the lowest liquid surface exposed to atmosphere, so it has to be lower at greater heights, and it is the lowest just under the meniscus.

Comment: @JánLalinský , but if the glass is attracting the water, then can it be called surface tension? Surface tension is caused by attraction of one water molecule with another.  So it is force of cohesion which causes surface tension, but if the glass attracts the water, it is adhesive force, so can it be called surface tension, and will it have same properties as surface tension?

Comment: It is surface tension because it is due to the same kind of short-range forces, glass has surface too. It does not have the same strength, surface tension is function of pair of materials. Thus surface tension for water-air pair is different than for the water-glass pair.